# How to map nested array of objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logic

I have a use case where I need to make a query to a NoSql table (**AWS DynamoDb**),
 
which will return me a list,
each result further needs to query back on the same table.

**My table has 2 important columns -**
1. sub_service_id
2. parent_id

The query is made on the **parent_id** column of the table
each record will have only 1 parent_id,
 
but a parent_id can be present in multiple rows, therefore 1 parent can have multiple children.

**My table looks like follows -**
[image]

Except for the 1st call, all remaining calls on the **parent_id** field,
 
are made using the **sub_service_id** of each record.

As you can see in the image,
1st record is the parent of 2nd record,
2nd record is the parent of the 3rd record.

But theoretically, the 1st, 2nd and 3rd records can each have multiple children records.
The NoSql table (AWS DynamoDb) can be queried using the Primary Key(sub_service_id) or an Index (parent_id)

**I tried the following code, but I'm not able to figure out the logic -**

```
var tree = {};
var requestBody = "";
module.exports.listServiceRelation = async (constants, requestBody) => {

    let requestContext = requestBody.context;
    requestBody = requestBody.request;

    let connection = await dynamoDb.getDynamoConnection(constants);
    console.log('db connection created!');

    let apiResponse = await getSubServiceHierarchy(constants, connection, requestBody.service_id);

};

let getSubServiceHierarchy = async (constants, connection, parent_id) => {

    let subServices = await dynamoDb.getSubServiceByParentId(constants, connection, parent_id);

    if(subServices != undefined && subServices.Items != undefined && subServices.Items.length > 0){

        let subServicesArr = [];
        for(let i in subServices.Items){
            let temp = {};

            let currObj = subServices.Items[i];

            temp.sub_service_id = currObj.sub_service_id;
            temp.sub_service_name = currObj.sub_service_name;
            temp.parent_id = currObj.parent_id;

            subServicesArr.push(temp);
        }
        tree[parent_id] = subServicesArr;

        for(let i in subServices.Items){
            let currObj = subServices.Items[i];

            let grandChildren = await dynamoDb.getSubServiceByParentId(constants, connection, currObj.sub_service_id);

            if(grandChildren != undefined && grandChildren.Items != undefined && grandChildren.Items.length > 0){
                getSubServiceHierarchy(constants, connection, grandChildren);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        return [];
    }
};
```

I need help with a pseudo-code logic for my use case,
**My Output needs to be something like this -**

```
[
    {
        "sub_service_id": "1",
        "parent_id": "main_service_id",
        "children": [{
            "sub_service_id": "2",
            "parent_id": "1",
            "children": [{
                "sub_service_id": "3",
                "parent_id": "2",
                "children": []
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "sub_service_id": "4",
        "parent_id": "main_service_id",
        "children": []
    }
]
```

Comment: I doubt you'll get any help with this problem. You should probably boil down what the exact problem is (i.e. exactly where your code is breaking) before posting on here. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hoping for some logic/approach related help :/

Comment: Your post is too long. Probably full of details that are irrelevant. I didn't read it, doubt anyone else will. StackOverflow is more a place for clear and direct questions and answers. If you're looking for a code review, you can head over to: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/